# JS: Select any avatar from a folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, random

So I'm working on some project and in some part of the website, I do need to show random avatar images from a specific folder, each X seconds (I'm using setInterval for this).

BUT the problem is that I can't select random images.

So basically this is a part of my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#avatar').attr('src', 'assets/img/avatars/*.jpg');
}, 1500);
```

As you can see, I've tried that *.jpg but it doesn't work.

Do you have any other ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: To make this work you will need a way of reading all the available image paths in to an array (either hard-coding them, or by calling some server side logic to retrieve them) then you can select a random path from the array and set it as the img src

Answer (score 1):

As Rory McCrossan  suggested, You can create an array which will contains all the avatar images.
After that in your setInterval function you use the Math.Random to generate a random integer from the given array length and based on that fetch the avatar and show it.

```js
var avatars = [
"img/pic1.jpg",
"img/pic2.jpg",
"img/pic3.jpg",
"img/pic4.jpg",
"img/pic5.jpg"
];

setInterval(function(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * avatars.length);
  var item = avatars[random];
  $('#avatar').attr('src', item);
  $('#avatar').attr('alt', item);
},2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="avatar" alt=""/ >
```

Comment: I already did that, before making this topic. But the thing is that I do need to put about 2-300 avatars so it's a pain in the *** to put them all in an array.

Comment: Where does your avatar list resides? Is it on a server side or in json file or a service?

Comment: I'm not sure I got you. But they're located in a folder (local one) which I'm gonna upload on the server later.

Comment: In that case I suggest you to move this javascript logic to server-side and expose an API endpoint which will give an random avatar image url whenever you invoke that API. Also from performance point of view I would also suggest you to integrate service worker in your client side application for faster image loading.